# setup SSO for Jira 8.1 and confluence with cas

Tags: single-sign-on, jira, keycloak, cas, jasig

I am configuring JIRA and confluence with sso using jasig cas step by step details given [here](https://www.ascendintegrated.com/integrating-jira-sso-using-cas/) is not full setup of CAS and JIRA configuration. how can i configure cas with Jira and confluence?

also tried to setup using saml and keycloak but was not able to make it work